# Why I cannot pass my parameter python

Tags: python, parameters

I wrote a simple function to calculate mode, but it seems one parameter does not pass successfully.

I initial `countdict= dict()` in the main function, then I pass it `mod = mode(magList, countdict)`.

In `mode(alist, countdict)`, `countdict= dict(zip(alist,[0]*len(alist)))`. and `countdict` can print in mode.

but when I try to  `print(countdict)` in main function, the output says it is empty. I check my code, it says in function mode, I unused countdict. How could that be possible.

The whole code is as following:

```
def mode(alist, countdict):
    countdict= dict(zip(alist,[0]*len(alist)))
    for x in alist:
        countdict[x]+=1
    maxcount =max(countdict.values()) 
    modelist = [ ]    
    for item in countdict:
        if countdict[item] == maxcount:
            modelist.append(item)
    return modelist



def makeMagnitudeList():
        quakefile = open("earthquakes.txt","r")
        headers = quakefile.readline()

        maglist = [ ]
        for aline in quakefile:
            vlist = aline.split()
            maglist.append(float(vlist[1]))
        return maglist

def mymain():
    magList = makeMagnitudeList()
    print(magList)
    countdict= dict()
    mod = mode(magList, countdict)
    print("mode: ", mod)
    print(countdict)

if __name__=='__main__':
    mymain()
```

Comment: I suspect it's because `countdict` is getting reassigned in the first line of the `mode` function.

Comment: You are missunderstanding some concepts about global and local variable. The `countdict` you have in your main is not the same as the  `countdict` in the function, they are completely different variables. Maybe this help you [Python pass variable by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said earlier, the line:

```
countdict= dict(zip(alist,[0]*len(alist)))
```

will wipe out the reference to `countdict` that you passed in. Because of this, the `countdict` variable you are printing is the original, empty dictionary. The question Liarez linked to: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) will help explain why this is happening.

To get around this, you could change the return statement in the `mode` function to:

```
return (modelist, countdict)
```

which will return a tuple containing both `modelist` and `countdict`. When calling this function, you would write:

```
(mod, countdict) = mode(magList, countdict)
```

ensuring that the modified `countdict` is returned, meaning that your `print` function call should not output an empty dictionary.

The other thing to note is that the `countdict` you are passing into `mode` is empty anyway, so you may find it better to simply not pass this argument in and have `mode` take only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is your problem.

```
countdict= dict(zip(alist,[0]*len(alist)))
```

Python dictionaries are mutable objects and can be changed in a function, however, dictionary itself is not passed to the function. Only reference is passed and is passed by value. It means that when you assign a new dictionary to your `countdict` parameter, you lose the original reference pointing at `countdict` created in your `mymain` function.